# Which encoding/charset we have to use Japanese data in Spark?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, encoding, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load all the country data format and at present, I have used Japanese data to load through spark. I am able to load the data and while displaying data I am getting a question marks in data. Please help me which charset I have to use.

I am using Spark 2.3.1 and scala 2.11.8 versions on Windows.

Here is my code:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("charset","UTF-8")
  .option("inferSchema","true").load("c:\\data\\japan.csv")

val resdata = spark.sql("select * from rxdata").show()
```

Here, I am getting question marks in my data. Please find the screenshot.

[Japan data charset issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTeWT.png)

Which charset do I have to use? Many thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2016/09/15/pyspark-how-to-handle-non-ascii-characters-and-connect-in-a-spark-dataframe/

Comment: Hi all, Any idea on this charset ? Please help me.

Comment: Hi all, Any help on this appreciate it. Many thanks.

Comment: can you add some sample input?